# SwiftUi - Interstitial Ad causing view disappearance when returning to a UITextField

Tags: xcode, swiftui, admob

When a UITextField is tapped, the keyboard appears as expected. However, after displaying an interstitial ad and returning to the same UITextField, the keyboard pushes up all the views, causing some views to disappear from the screen.

[Here is more detail in video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZPEJ.gif)

I used `@EnvironmentObject var adsViewModel: AdsViewModel` and `.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded{ adsViewModel.showInterstitial = true })` to show ads.

Main View:

```
@main
struct PertukApp: App {

    let adsVM = AdsViewModel.shared
    
    init(){
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = [GADSimulatorID]
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environmentObject(adsVM)
        }
    }
```

AdsManager:

```
class AdsManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    private struct AdMobConstant {
        static let interstitial1ID = "ca-app-pub-9877420063334339/6051084944"
    }
    
    final class Interstitial: NSObject, GADFullScreenContentDelegate, ObservableObject {

        private var interstitial: GADInterstitialAd?
        
        override init() {
            super.init()
            requestInterstitialAds()
        }

        func requestInterstitialAds() {
            let request = GADRequest()
            request.scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
            ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { status in
                GADInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID: AdMobConstant.interstitial1ID, request: request, completionHandler: { [self] ad, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Failed to load interstitial ad with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        return
                    }
                    interstitial = ad
                    interstitial?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
                })
            })
        }
        
        func showAd() {
            if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
               let root = windowScene.windows.last?.rootViewController {
                
                if let fullScreenAds = interstitial {
                    fullScreenAds.present(fromRootViewController: root)
                } else {
                    print("not ready")
                }
            }
        }
        
        func adDidRecordImpression(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
            
        }
        
        func adDidRecordClick(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {}
        
        func ad(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd, didFailToPresentFullScreenContentWithError error: Error) {
            requestInterstitialAds()
        }
        
        func adWillPresentFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
            requestInterstitialAds()
        }
            
        func adWillDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {}
            
        func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {}
        
    }
    
    
}


class AdsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = AdsViewModel()
    @Published var interstitial = AdsManager.Interstitial()
    @Published var showInterstitial = false {
        didSet {
            if showInterstitial {
                interstitial.showAd()
                showInterstitial = false
            } else {
                interstitial.requestInterstitialAds()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you found a solution? The problem seems to be in `windowScene.windows.last?.rootViewController`. If you ever use a text field, your app creates a new window, or so it seems, and then you display the ad in that very window (`windows.last`), which seems to cause the issue later on. Now, if you use `windows.first`, you won’t have *this* issue, but the ad won’t show at all…